# Как в объект лучше всего добавить содержимое другого объекта (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let obj1 = { a : 1, b : 2};
let obj2 = { c : 3, a : 4};
```

какая-то магия и бац (порядок не важен)

```
obj1 = { a : 4, b : 2, c : 3};
```

Уважаемые программисты, обратите внимание что я присваиваю значение в obj1.

мне на ум приходит только что-то такое:

```
obj1 = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

какие ещё есть варианты?)
Может кто-то знает решение при котором не нужно пересоздавать объект, и можно просто добавить значение в старый (уже созданный)?

Comment: `obj1 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj1 = { a : 1, b : 2}
let obj2 = { c : 3, a : 4}

const obj3 = Object.assing(obj1, obj2)
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить чем будет отличаться способ obj1 = {...obj1, ...obj2}; от obj1 = Object.assing(obj1, obj2)

Comment: @Tenshi ваш вариант построен на чистой деструктуризации, красиво — да, понятно с ходу — не очень. `Object.assing` Это метод копирования внутри `JS` он просто понятнее. Как-то так.

Comment: `...` (`spread operator`) под капотом `Object.assign` в современных браузерах, посмотрите на скомпилированный код `babel` или `typescript`, это применимо к объекту, при работе с массивами `...` компилируется в `slice`

Comment: @overthesanity речь идёт не о `Babel`, `spread` Уже нормально поддерживается `V8` И другими современными движками.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, речь шла не о `babel`, но человек просто спросил чем отличаются способы, я ответил, что `spread` это синтаксический сахар, к Вашему ответу я не предираюсь